# Asterisk on Ubuntu desktop

Tags: 14.04, server, voip, asterisk

Ok, so this the situation: I want to install Asterisk (mainly for the IVR system) on an Ubuntu desktop 14.04. For space limits I cannot have a second PC in the room so i have to relay on the one PC i can have. Also, I cannot convert it into a server because I need to be able to use it.

So the question is: can I install Asterisk on a desktop pc? and can I continue to use the desktop (ex. web surfing) while Asterisk is up an running?

The current PC is: 8GB Ram, 1TB HDD, AMD64 6Core.

I would like to be able to use it with Gvoice and/or Obihai 202.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your Ubuntu desktop PC as a server. It will keep on working, as long as it's powered on of course.

The difference between an server and desktop is the GUI, and most servers in data centers don't have their own keyboard, mouse and screen. Aside from that, you normally don't install LibreOffice or Firefox on a server, and many other libraries and tools.

It's not good practice to install all these applications on a server. Just what you need. A database server doesn't need a webserver, so you don't install Apache, etc. Keep it as simple as possible. This keeps the risk of crashes to a minimum, plus it's more secure, less attack vectors.

For you this is of no importance. Use whatever you need.